# Android game design

Tags: java, android

I'm working on designing a game with multiple levels and was wondering if I was going about it the right way. I have a menu screen with levels to choose from, and each level(button) would start a new activity specifically for that level. Is that a good practice or just terribly inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is it a good practice, it is perhaps the only practice. You might consider giving these links a good read and understand the basics. :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: I see no reason why having an activity per game level is the only way of doing things, can you elaborate on why is that?

Comment: Not saying that at all. I am working on an app which involves opening a lot of activities. Android is quite a capable OS in itself and it manages activities very well. I don't see how else could this chap start a new level when a specific button for a specific level is pressed. He can always close the activity stack when moving to a different activity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is the only practice, but is the best practice there is, if you try to make too many activities you will only make the game go slow

Comment: That's not necessarily true at all. In fact, that would only be true for very poorly implemented activities.